# Dúvida sobre a biblioteca gráfica GTK+ (Desenhando uma Arvore B na linguagem C)

Tags: c, árvore-binária, gtk

Boa tarde,

Recentemente eu tive um trabalho que era basicamente a implementação em Linguagem C com interface gráfica de uma Árvore-B, o programa deveria permitir e mostrar as operações de inserção, remoção e pesquisa, reconstruindo a árvore a cada passo.

Gostaria de saber se há uma biblioteca gráfica que facilite o processo de desenho da árvore, ou seja, que providencie procedimentos para desenhar formas geométricas.

Atualmente estou tentando usar o `Glade` (e a biblioteca `GTK+`) para o processo, mas sou iniciante com a ferramenta.